# Setting href link target without reloading page

Tags: html, href, target

I have a href tag `<a href="#somepage" target="sometarget">` or more accurately loading a URL from Flash `loadURL('#somepage', 'sometarget')`. I have no option to remove the target so am limited to (I assume) the available targets: `_top`, `_self`, `_blank`, `_parent`.

What target or alternative do I have to avoid refreshing the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

target="_self" is the default. It is the same as having no target at all.